# Does underscore mean something special in c# regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to search a for a specific string in an HTML file. The string I am looking for is

```
HHA_HG
```

If I use notepad I can see that the string only exists once in the file.

However

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(inputString, "HHA_HG");
```

Returns no matches. I verify the inputString contains the string I want.

The weird thing is if I remove all the lines apart from the line containing HHA_HG I can get a match. If I just search for HHA_ in the full file I can get matches although none of the matches are HHA_HG.

Does the underscore mean something special?

Comment: No, it doesn't: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: is there a `\n` after HHA_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. That should be fine. Possible explanation: is there an invisible unicode character in either the source or regex pattern? Or alternative "looks like an A but isn't an A" unicode characters? Basically, what are the actual `char` values in both the regex pattern and the file (at the appropriate location)? Is the HHA_HG in the file actually in a RTL block, and is actually GH_AHH ?

Comment: I thought it might be some hidden character, but in notepad i am finding the string using ascii i typed in. Is it possible for something in the source to cause the regex to terminate before it reach the line i want?

Comment: @hwnd are there invisible line-breaks? i.e. that the OP wouldn't be able to see?

Comment: There could be invisible control characters in which `\s` itself will not handle and could suffice for trying something like `[\0\pC\pZ]+` or as you stated possible accented characters.

Comment: @hwnd ah, indeed; ultimately the next step here is for the OP to find out what the actual chars are in this region.

Comment: @mfc it's all Greek to me